# CatalogSearch Rewrite Rule Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to use Apache HTTPD to change the rewrite URL for any request to be re-written as `catalogsearch/result/?q=`

If I put these lines in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+catalogsearch/result/\?q=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /q/%1? [L,NE,R=301]
RewriteRule ^q/(.*)$ /catalogsearch/result/?q=$1 [L,NE,QSA]
```

it always results in a 404 error... (although the url is correctly rewritten).

Can you help me please to solve?

Comment: Can you show me the final url you are getting?

Comment: if i search for apple:
www.mysite.com/q/apple